# В простом listView элемент списка "подсвечивается" неполностью

Tags: android, listview

Пытаюсь сделать наипростейший listView. создаю лэйаут:

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/history_menu_item"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:padding="10dp"
     android:text="TextView"
     android:textSize="24sp" > </TextView>
```

И ListActivity:

```
 public class HistoryMenu extends
 ListActivity {     public void
 onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        String[] values = new String[] {
 "Edit", "Send" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new
 ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.history_menu, values);         setListAdapter(adapter);    } }
```

Элемент списка выделяется в итоге не полностью,  а только там, где текст. Как сделать чтобы элемент выделялся полностью?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Comment: match_parent разве не deprected? мне часто говорит использовать fill_parent

Comment: по-моему наоборот (и кстати у вас высота именно этой константой задана). Да и на самом деле значение одно и то же

Comment: ой, это не Ваш вопрос)

Comment: а точняк, напутал

Comment: >fill_parent: The view should be as big as its parent (minus >padding). This constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and >is replaced by match_parent.